# JS Regex to match with a space before special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to pull out a series of words starting with special characters from a string. My code is:

```
var specialChars = "!#^@>-/*";
var firstSpecialCharIndex = inputString.search(/[\\!\\#\\^\\@\\>\\\-\\/\\*]/);
var plainText = inputString.substring(0, firstSpecialCharIndex);
var result = {};
result["text"] = plainText;

for (i = firstSpecialCharIndex + 1; i < inputString.length;) {
    var modifiedString = inputString.substring(i);

    var currentChar = inputString.charAt(i - 1);
    if (result[currentChar] == null)
        result[currentChar] = [];
    var text = "";
    var specialCharIndex = modifiedString.search(/[\\!\\#\\^\\@\\>\\\-\\/\\*]/);
    if (specialCharIndex != -1) {
         text = modifiedString.substring(0, specialCharIndex);
        text = text.trim();
        result[currentChar].push(text);
        i += specialCharIndex + 1;
    } else {
        text = modifiedString.substring(0);
        text = text.trim();
        result[currentChar].push(text);
        i = inputString.length;
    }
}
```

Now this sort of works, and correctly turns the string:

```
String start ^a #b #c @d >e *f /g
```

into:

```
{"text":"String start ","^":["a"],"#":["b","c"],"@":["d"],">":["e"],"*":["f"],"/":["g"]}
```

The issue is with using the characters in the original string. Currently, the Regex thinks that `string@string` should match to `@string` when it shouldn't. **I want to only match when there is a space before a special character.**

Is it possible to require a space before using the Regex? Is there any other way to the Regex should be cleaned up, or is it correct for its purpose? Or would I need to write some more JS to check the values then clean them up or something?

Many thanks

Comment: First, change regex to `[!#^@>/*-]`

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAyoub, although this does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
/ ([!#^@>\/*-]\w+)/gm
```

With this code:

```js
var result = {};


var re = / ([!#^@>\/*-]\w+)/gm; 
var str = 'lorem ipsum http://google.com -h ';
var m;

var firstSpecialCharIndex = str.search(/ [!#^@>\/*-]/);
result["text"] = str.substring(0, firstSpecialCharIndex);


while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
  }

  var index = m[1].substring(0,1);
  if(result[index] == null)
    result[index] = [];
  result[index].push(m[1].substring(1));
}


console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works, except that it doesn't match if the start string is `str/ing` - Ideally I want it to recognise this whole portion as the string. Is there a way to 'escape' the characters when they are included in a word? Thanks

Comment: How would you tell if it's a word or not? @samiles

Comment: Well the special chars should *only* match when there is a space before it. So `stri/ng /word` would be `(stri/ng)(/word)` and `stri /ng /work` would be `(stri)(/ng,/work)`. Hope that's clear :)

Comment: For example, I want `lorem ipsum http://google.com` to be recognised as a string at the start, not break at `lorem ipsum http:` when it hits the / unless there's a space before.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly now! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/\s[!#^@>\-/*]/
```

`\s` matches all white space characters `[\r\n\t\f ]`

or if you just want a plain old space, not to include newlines or tabs

```
/ [!#^@>\-/*]/
```

Also you shouldn't need to escape all your backslashes that are already escaping things, nor do you need to escape anything except the `-`

Comment: That stops it matching without a space, but unfortunately it stops the rest of the code working - it doesn't get any of the results for the special characters and just returns an empty array. I will keep playing with this space in the reggae though, thanks.